# How to display from time to time items from an array inside an array using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following HTML with a `v-for` to display 3 paragraphs: Name, Details and Suite.

I need to display only 2 items at once so what I'm trying to do is display the first item on the array (ideally it should be first two items, now it's wrapped in one using `\n`).

***Eg.***

Company B

Lorem Ipsum

Dolor sit amet

**After 5 seconds**

Company B

Lorem Dolor Ipsum

Amet Dollor sit

---

```
<v-row
  class="pt-0 mt-0"
  v-for="item in myItemsA"
  :key="item.Name"
>
  <v-col cols="12" md="10" class="py-0 my-0">
    <p class="custom-title font-weight-regular mb-0">{{ item.Name }}</p>
    <p class="pre-formatted custom-body-1 font-weight-light mb-2">{{ item.Details }}</p>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="2" class="py-0 my-0">
    <p class="custom-title font-weight-regular text-center">{{ item.Suite }}</p>
  </v-col>
</v-row>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return: {
      myItemsA: [
        {
          Name: 'Company A',
          Details: [
            'Lorem Ipsum \nDolor sit amet',
            'Lorem Dolor Ipsum \nAmet Dollor sit',
            'Dolor amet Lorem \nAmet Sir Lorem Dolor'
          ],
          Suite: '1'
        },
        {
          Name: 'Company B',
          Details: [
            'Lorem Ipsum',
            'Dolor sit amet',
            'Lorem Dolor Ipsum',
            'Amet Dollor sit',
            'Dolor amet Lorem',
            'Amet Sir Lorem Dolor'
          ],
          Suite: '2'
        },
        {
          Name: 'Company C',
          Details: [
            'Lorem Ipsum',
            'Dolor sit amet',
            'Lorem Dolor Ipsum',
            'Amet Dollor sit',
            'Dolor amet Lorem',
            'Amet Sir Lorem Dolor'
          ],
          Suite: '3'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.updateDescription()
    }, 5000)
  },
  methods: {
    updateDescription() {
      const first = this.Details.shift();
      this.Details = this.Details.concat(first);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

My code is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of behaviour is easiest to achieve by creating a component that takes as input an array and displays only the items you want; that way you can encapsulate all the logic into a separate component.

```js
Vue.component('carousel', {
  template: '#carousel',
  
  props: ['items'],
  
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
    };
  },
  
  computed: {
    item() {
      return this.items[this.index % this.items.length]
    },
  },
  
  created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.index++, 5000)
  },
  
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Company A',
        details: [
          'Details A 1',
          'Details A 2',
          'Details A 3',
          'Details A 4',
        ],
        suite: 'Suite A',
      },
      {
        name: 'Company B',
        details: [
          'Details B 1',
          'Details B 2',
          'Details B 3',
        ],
        suite: 'Suite B',
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item of items" class="item">
    <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
    <carousel :items="item.details"></carousel>
    <div>{{ item.suite }}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="carousel">
  <div>{{ item }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!